# Video frames get stuck on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, video

I am a newbie to Ubuntu.
I have a clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. 
My system information:-
Memory: 3.7 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4 
Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
GNOME: 3.28.1
OS: 64 bit

The problem I am facing is that whenever I stream videos on the internet, the video gets stuck on a frame and the audio keeps playing and after a few seconds the current video frame is displayed. So many frames of video get missed. I have tried a different browser and different sites too. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: are you streaming 4k (or similarly high resolution) via browser?

Comment: The problem exists even if I stream low-resolution videos even on youtube, but it's definitely more in high-resolution videos.

Comment: If you run `mpv http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov`, does it run smoothly?

Comment: when I go to the link, it starts downloading a video. I use VLC player to run local videos and they run smoothly. I am having problem only with streaming videos online.

Comment: In the browser you won't get hardware acceleration. I just wanted to make sure if you can play accelerated with mpv or vlc

Comment: Oh. So do you know any way I can fix this?

Comment: use mpv or vlc :) Or help implementing vaapi/vdpau support in firefox.

Comment: ok, this is a new way for me. So in the terminal, I tried "vlc <link of youtube video"  and it run using vlc player smoothly. But does this work for all websites?

Comment: I just tried with other websites. The trick is to find the link for the video file, isn't it?

Comment: mpv can play youtube links directly

Comment: what about vimeo videos?

Comment: no idea. https://www.bountysource.com/issues/55506502-add-va-api-hardware-decoding-support-on-linux